# Can I inherit from a class if base class doesn't have constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

So I have a `Vehicle` class without a constructor. I want to make a new class called `VehicleExtended` which *inherits* from `Vehicle`.
The error is:

> 'Vehicle' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments (CS1729)

Is it possible to inherit without having a constructor?

NOTE: I can't edit the base class because it's only it's metadata that I can see.

```
public class VehicleData : Vehicle
{
    [BsonId]public int _id { get; private set;}
    public bool IsCompany { get; private set;}
    public int OwnerID { get; private set; }
    public string modelName { get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: **Every** class has a constructor.

Comment: Its impossible to not have a constructor. If you don't provide one, a default zero-argument constructor will be generated. Your error message suggests that this is not the case, that there is a constructor which takes arguments.

Comment: Could you please add `Vehicle`s code also? As tkausl assumed the base-class has a constructor which may have parameters.

Comment: `'Vehicle' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments` means it **has** a constructor which takes 1 or more parameters.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5m9PMHX.png
Yeah I get it now.
The problem is the Vehicle class has no constructor defined (I can't see it in the medata).

Comment: Could you provide the metadata for the `Vehicle`-class. Also you said you want to create a class called `VehicleExtended` but provided metadata for a class called `VehicleData`, could you please clarify the names of the classes involved?

Comment: `ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfo = typeof(Vehicle).GetConstructors();`
@shlime just found out constructor define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see from the error message, base class `Vehicle` *doesn't have* constructors *without arguments*:

```
  public class Vehicle { 
    ...
    // every Vehicle constructors want some parameters, e.g. id and ownerId
    public Vehicle(int id, int ownerId) {...}
    ...
  }
```

That's the compiler *doesn't know* how to create instance of `VehicleData`:

```
  // Since VehicleData is inherited from Vehicle, 
  // Vehicle cosntructor should be executed.
  // What arguments should be passed to it?   
  var test = new VehicleData();
```

You have to implement `VehicleData` constructor *manually* in which you should specify the arguments:

```
  public class VehicleData : Vehicle 
  {
    // When creating an instace, use -1 and -1 when calling base constructor
    public VehicleData() : base(-1, -1) {}

    ...
  }
```

Now the code above is *legal*:

```
  // We don't want parameters when creating VehicleData instance
  // When creating base class (Vehicle) -1 and -1 are used  
  var test = new VehicleData();
```

**Edit:** If *base class* (`Vehicle`) *doesn't have* any `public` or `protected` constructors (but `private` ones) you can't create base `Vehicle` instance from `VehicleData` and thus can't inherit from `Vehicle`. `private` constructors only is an old **C++** trick; in case of **C#** in order to *prevent from inheriting*  we should use `sealed`

Comment: You can use private constructors for singletons also. So they aren´t *entirely* useless - just an asside.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, that the base class has a *private* constructor which can't be accessed. In this case you can't inherit the class.

Comment: That would throw a `Vehicle not accessable due to protecteton-level`-error.

Comment: @HimBromBeere depends a bit on how you look at it. If you add a parameter to the private constructor you'll get this message, and in that case this answer is correct in saying you can't inherit the class.

Comment: @Knoop But then its about the additional parameter, not the constructor being private.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that wouldn't magically make it possible to inherit it. This answer states there is a possibility it has a private constructor (does not say anything about if that constructor has arguments or not) and stating that in that case you can't inherit the class.

Comment: @Knoop But OPs question was not why we can´t inherit a class having a private constructor, but why OPs error appears. And as I see it, the error is **not** due to a private constructor, so arguing on what we can do or not when a class has a private constructor is pointless here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere actually it being private **is** part of it. Change your fiddle to a public constructor that takes an argument and the error message will become `'Compilation error (line 14, col 14): There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '{name}' of 'C.C({type})'`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message I assume that the class `VehicleData` has an private zero argument constructor.
In this case you can not inherit from `VehicleData`.
e.g.

```cs
public class A
{
    private A() {}
}
public class B : A
{
}
```

this will not compile.
But if there is an public or protected with a non-zeor argument list you can inherit from the class:

```cs
public class A
{
    private A() {}
    public A(int i) {}
}
public class B : A
{
    public B() : base(0) {}
}
```

Also, if it turns out that `Vehicle` has only `private` constructores and you only want to add specificy behaivor and not any kinds of properties that are not computable from the ones that are already defined in `Vehicle`, instead of inheriting you could use extesnions-methodes.

```cs
public static VehicleExtesnion
{
    public SomeType DoStuff(this Vehicle vehicle) 
    {
        // do stuff with vehicle
    }
}
```